# How to include Google Maps in Ionic Page with no Internet fallback

Tags: google-maps, typescript, angular, ionic2

I need to use the Google Maps Javascript API inside my ionic application for one Page. Currently I'm integrating the source in the index.html with:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&libraries=places"></script>
```

Problem: When I've got no/a slow internet connection the Ionic Application won't show until this script is loaded.

How can I integrate this script only in the required Page and show a Message if it can't load?

Comment: I think [this post](http://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-advanced-google-maps-component-in-ionic-2/) from Josh Morony is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Great! Later I'll add the main concepts as an answer so other users with the same issue could solve it easier.